# Querying scss map to position div based on index

Tags: css, for-loop, sass, maps

I have a review system that I’ve been working on that has a white stencil of some stars, that are filled by moving an absolutely positioned div behind it.

The scss map has some percentages on it that I want to use to position this div.

The example class `.review-note-2` is just an example of how php fills the div, based on the review count.

**Aim:** To loop through the map and assign the left value of this `.review-note- class` that is in the scss map.

**scss:**

```
$position: (
  0:    -100%,
  1:    -86%,
  2:    -64%,
  3:    -38%,
  4:    -17%,
  5:    0% 
);

.product-review-rates {
    width:428px;
    display:inline-block;

    .review-stars {
        background:url('star-stencil.svg') no-repeat;
        width:100%;
        z-index:1;
        display:inline-block;
        height:150px;
        background-size: 428px 60px;
        overflow:hidden;

        & > div {
        position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eb93b7;
    left:-100%;
    height: 60px;
        }
      @for $i from 0 through 5 {
            .review-note-#{$i} { 
            left:0px; // query $position map above
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="product-review-rates">
   <div class="review-stars">
      <div class="review-note-2"></div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

**(nearly) working example:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MayvYE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering own question (cringes!):

```
 $position: (
      0:    -100%,
      1:    -86%,
      2:    -64%,
      3:    -38%,
      4:    -17%,
      5:    0% 
    );
    @each $starNo, $value in $position{
            .review-note-#{$starNo} { 
               left:$value;
            }
    }
```

**Link:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQwZoK